# Amount of empty spaces to print each number after last one ends

Tags: php, fibonacci

I'm trying to print Fibonacci sequence in a browser window with PHP. Simply I just want that each next number would start at the column where last number ended. So that i could achieve effect like this:

[image]

For this effect i've used such code:

```
<?php

list($a, $b) = [0,1];
$sp=0;

while (true) {
    if ((int)$a < 0) {     
        break;
    }
    else {
        for ($i=0; $i < $sp; $i++) {
            echo("&nbsp;");
        }
        echo ("$a<br>");
        // don't understand why double amount of spaces needed
        $sp += 2 * strlen($a);        
        list($a, $b) = [$b, $a+$b];        
    }
}
```

Question is - Why I need **twice** as many empty spaces as last number length ?

Comment: it should work just fine without `2` as well

Comment: Nope, it doesn't - in that case next number column overlaps with previous number columns

Comment: its just formatting problem. it would technically work without overlap without 2 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the default browser font is not a monospace font, and spaces take about half the horizontal space as digits.

Try it within a `<pre>` tag (which implies a monospace font) , and you'll notice the difference:

```
<?php

list($a, $b) = [0,1];
$sp=0;

echo  "<pre>";

foreach (range(0,20) as $n) {
    if ((int)$a < 0) {     
        break;
    }
    else {
        for ($i=0; $i < $sp; $i++) {
            echo("&nbsp;");
        }
        echo ("$a<br>");
        // don't understand why double amount of spaces needed
        $sp += 2 * strlen($a);        
        list($a, $b) = [$b, $a+$b];        
    }
}

echo  "</pre>";

?>
```

When you run the above code, the output will have too much space in each line, so now you need to remove `2 *` to make it align correctly.